# Toggle input type radio on click event or mousedown event

Tags: jquery

The problem is that when I have an alert in my `mousedown` event I can uncheck the radio button. On the other hand, when I don't have an alert in my `mousedown` event I can't achieve the same result.

Would anyone would be able to explain why?

```
$('.toggler').on('mousedown', function() {
    alert($(this).prop("checked"));
    if($(this).prop("checked") === true){
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }else {
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Here is a link to [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wz5BA/159/)

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `alert()` inside `mousedown` , `.click` event never completes since alert box opens up before `mouseup` event. So without alert you have to explicitly prevent `.click` like below.

you can add below snippet in your code

```
    $('.toggle').on('click', function(e) {       
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

you need to prevent default `.click` event

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wz5BA/161/

For more details on mouse events, refer [this link](http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events#simple-events)

Comment: I see so is the default browser  behaviour  to check a radio button is a click event so in that case it e.prevent it will not cause the radio to be checked at all then i can manipulate as I like :) Great Thank's for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Updated link for mouse event details. You might find it useful

Comment: it's a great link  "Events fire order
A single action may cause multiple events. For example, a click actually causes mousedown, mouseup and click in sequence" this was very usefull

Comment: @JulianoVargas - Just a tip. You can accept the answer by ticking checkmark, so that question will be marked as answered